# PHP Two-Dimensional Array Form Handling

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

I've been stumped on this for a couple of nights now.  I don't seem to be able to pass a value from a two-dimensional array to my very simple form handler.  Yet, it works with a single dimension array.

The idea is, that I create a drop-down select/option list from a single field in a database table, first creating an array from the database, select the field from a single record, and pass its value on to my file handler routine for further processing. The mechanics of the array builder seem to work well enough, it is generating the items in my drop-down option list.  But, something about the value isn't working correctly.

```
    <?php

       include('activitiesdb_array_builder.php');

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>ddtest_003.php</title>
       </head>
       <body>
        <form action='ddtest_001_handler.php' method="POST">
         <select name="activity_name" size="5">
      
      <?php
    
       // Iterating through the name fields in the database array
     
         foreach($record as $rec) 
       {
          echo "<option value='$rec[name]'>$rec[name]</option>";
       }
      ?>
       </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting drop-down with your browser developer tools? Check what is inside `<option value></option>` attribute.

Comment: `echo "<option value='{$rec['name']}'>{$rec['name']}</option>";` There seems slight bug regarding using quotes.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, but, rewarding.  This morning, I tried the same bit of code on my laptop, removed the line  <!DOCTYPE html>, and....of course, it works just fine.  Arghh!  As for the solution by Umair Khan, I actually started with that syntax, with the single-quote around my key, that is $rec[

Comment: I kept getting bounced out above, and my edit took too long.  Thanks Keeprock, I never thought of using my browser development tools to inspect the value inside an option value.  I thought that the only way to see the value is with the file handler routine.  I'll have to remember that.  And Umair Khan.  I started by using the syntax that you suggest above, but, I ran into a nested quote/double-quote issue.  I was about to use a \' or a \" to see if that solved my issue.  But, now, even without the quotes around the name key, it seems to be working fine.